# Autocommand to add edited filename to bash history

Tags: autocmd

I do a lot of editing in vim and am constantly opening up files using `:e` or `:new` ...etc. However, when I quit vim, I do not have the files I edited in my `.bash_history`. Since I keep finding myself needing this, I thought I'd add an `au` recipe like:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *
\ [ check if %:p is same as new file being opened ...is that <afile>?? ] |
\         !history -s vim <...>
```

I was wondering whether there are any downsides to this ? and secondly, if not, what's the exact idiomatic vimscript way to express this ?

Edit: After a bit of reading, I discovered the `oldfiles` and `browse oldfiles` commands, so as an alternative way to solve my request -- what would be the set of vimscript spells to invoke that will tell vim -- open up the `oldfiles` in a buffer if no arguments were provided on the commandline (as opposed to an empty `:e` or `:new`) ? Essentially, override the vim welcome buffer (which has the centered text of version, help etc), with `oldfiles`

...or ...add the files edited in current session to bash_history on exit ...or a different way to achieve the same effect ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `browse oldfiles` you can create the following autocommand:

```
autocmd! VimEnter * if argc() == 0 | browse oldfiles | endif
```

It is triggered when Vim starts (`VimEnter`), it checks if any files were passed as parameter from the command line (`if argc() == 0`) and if none were passed it executes `browse oldfiles`.

For more details see

- [`:h autocommand-events`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocommand%2devents)
- [`:h argc()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#argc%28%29)

I don't think inserting the filenames in your bash history is a good idea because for at least two reasons:

- It might create entries that you don't want
- I don't know how you'd expected to record the different files but if you open two files and want to access them easily it can be a problem: if you record `vim file1` and `vim file2` you won't get a command to open both in your history, if you record `vim file1 file2` and want to repon only `file1` you get the opposite problem.

Also maybe you might want to check plugins such as [CtrlP](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) which allow you to get a list of Most Recent Used files don't I won't give you any advice about that because I've never used a plugin to do that.